# How to save selected item in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I want to ask how can save selected all item in tableViewCell like this picture below. so later I can post it with with alamofire, I don't have any experience with posting data before. here is what have I done.

[image: post]

this is my button so I can later post in with alamofire, so far I want to test it.

```
    @objc func handleSubmit() {
        var data: [String] = []
        for (index, value) in attendance.enumerated() {
            print("index attendance: \(index), value attendance: \(value.status)")
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)) as? GStudentAbsenceCell
        UserServices.shared.postUserAttendances(status: cell?.status ?? "")
            data.append(cell?.status ?? String(index))
        }
        print(data)
    }

// In My UITableViewCell
var status: String?

statusLbl.didSelect { (selectedText , index ,id) in
               if selectedText == "Sakit" || selectedText == "Izin" || selectedText == "Alpha" {
                self.status = selectedText
                   self.statusLbl.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8666666667, green: 0.4078431373, blue: 0.2705882353, alpha: 0.2)
                   self.statusLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8666666667, green: 0.4078431373, blue: 0.2705882353, alpha: 1)
               }
           }
```

Comment: create a model of cell and store and load based on selection

Comment: okey what you mean, but when I store the cell. what parameter I have to pass in my post request if I create model of cell? sorry @Vinodh this is my first time doing it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot safely store your data models state in a table view cell, because upon scrolling the cell will likely to be reused for newly visible rows, hence it will store the state for a different row and therefore will lose the "old" state.

You need to store the state in your model; if it's not feasible to use your existing model, you might create a transient dictionary which maps the `IndexPath` to the `state`

What you could do is the following:

1. Extend your Cell with a custom callback handler, which is called when the status is changed.
2. When you set up your cell, hand in a closure that will deal with those status changes
3. In that closure, update the model

Some pseudo code might help you:

```
// in your custom cell
typealias Handler: (String) -> ()
class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
     var selectionHandler:Handler?
     func didSelect(...) {
          selectionHandler?(lblStatus.text)
     }

}

// in your view controller
// in rowForCellatIndexPath:

func  tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
     let cell = /* dequeue */ as! CustomTableViewCell

     cell.selectionHandler = { statusText in
          let row = indexPath.row
          attendance[row].status = statusText /* get the status from the cell */
     }

     return cell
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry @AndreasOetjen I don't understand, this is my first time doing it. can you show me sample code?

Comment: Well, it's a lot to learnif you never did something like this. I'll update my answer a little, but I cannot provide too much code, because this would need knowledge of your project internals.

Comment: I see thank you @AndreasOetjen I try to understand piece by piece and google what you mean.